# Swipe UITableViewCell Delete Not commitEditingStyle in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableViewController, I want to swipe delete cell. Already connected to dataSource and delegate.

it randomly detecting,
some times console prints

```
attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good
```

He is my code,

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    }
}
```

**Edit**

My cellForRow AtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kFavouriteCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self customizeFavouriteCell:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: double check your method signature should be exactly same.

Comment: @NeverHopeless : yes.

Comment: Can u plz show us the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: We need more from cellForRowAIndexPath to investigate, did you add gestures on UITableView or its superview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the data for the cell, and delete the cell. Using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Inside this protocol function:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // ... delete data here ...
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have a more specific question about doing either of these.

Comment: when swipe not calling "commitEditingStyle " method

Comment: It should be, especially if you're using a TableViewController. This may sound stupid, but are you positive your code looks like what you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:                   
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
//add code here for when you hit delete      
}
}
```

Comment: This is the same the above answer .